# HJow to add property in the request during 'prepareForValidation'

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 6.

I have this POST (for api usage) :

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/schools/d4866265-3965-4b91-8d0a-a621c9eb68c6/periods/854624d4-69b2-419b-9763-416b5d146e2d/exams/bd0127fe-185a-42f5-b121-15f856daee43
```

I use the formRequest validation. Like this :

```
public function rules(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'classroom_id' => [
            'required',
            new CoherenceSchoolPeriodClassroom($request->school_id, $request->period_id),
        ],
```

As you see, I need the $request->school_id for the test. But this data is not on the request payload, but present on the route.

So I would like to add this data using the prepareForValidation method :

```
protected function prepareForValidation(): void
{
    $this->merge([
        'school_id' => 'the school_id present on the route'
    ]);
}
```

My question is : how to get the school_id present in the route and merge it in request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your route parameter is called `school_id`, you can access it as a property or with the `route()` method.

```
'school_id' => $this->route('school_id')
// or
'school_id' => $this->school_id
```

If you only need it to validate the `classroom_id` you don't have to merge it into the request:

```
public function rules(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'classroom_id' => [
            'required',
            new CoherenceSchoolPeriodClassroom($this->route('school_id'), $request->period_id),
        ],
...
```

But you can merge it like so:

```
protected function prepareForValidation(): void
{
    $this->merge([
       'school_id' => $this->route('school_id')
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Hi Remul, thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot. I must done **$this->route('school')->id** No need to use prepareForValidation() method.